# Is possible to extract the runtime version from WASM file?

Tags: rust, wasm, subwasm

Is possible to extract the runtime version from the WASM file?

Sometimes, I want to verify the WASM file's content locally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tldr: Yes it is possible :)

There is a tool (and a bunch of crates) that actually aims at getting as many info as possible from a substrate wasm blob without requiring any node, it is called `subwasm`: https://github.com/chevdor/subwasm

**IMPORTANT**: Make sure to install from the repo and **not from crates.io**. See repo for details.

If you don't have a runtime at hand, `subwasm` can help you fetch one quickly:

```
subwasm get --chain westend -o /tmp/runtime.wasm
```

Assuming you have a runtime as `/tmp/runtime.wasm`, you can use either the `info` or the (new) `version` command, for instance:

```
subwasm info /tmp/westend.wasm --json | jq -r .core_version.specVersion
```

It will return `9260` (currently). This call does NOT require a node and work totally offline.

`subwasm` can get you more information, the same way the Polkadot release notes show runtimes, for instance:

```
subwasm info /tmp/runtime.wasm
```

will output:

```
Running subwasm v0.18.0
️  Runtime size:                1.138 MB (1,193,760 bytes)
  Compressed:                  Yes, 80.61%
✨ Reserved meta:                OK - [6D, 65, 74, 61]
 Metadata version:             V14
 Core version:                 westend-9260 (parity-westend-0.tx11.au2)
️  system.setCode hash:         0xb98632189a72582b350912cd4b70fe393fe71140c1f7ed7a95082dd95a3db8ae
️  authorizeUpgrade hash:       0x1dd000c1b9c9d2f1df4f5fde6ea6965b32b1aba0b207e8da8e93773123c3d49c
#️⃣  Blake2-256 hash:             0x6190bd415a14354629aee74dbb1a0c907ea800acd2a0842d8184b86185e4dde3
 IPFS:                         https://www.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXW<...>H8SwGFGWEyJ4
```

If you are more focused on the version itself, you can use the (fairly recent) `version` command:

```
subwasm version /tmp/westend.wasm
```

which will output:

```
Running subwasm v0.18.0
specifications : westend v9260
implementation : parity-westend v0
transaction    : v11
authoring      : v2
```

Most commands output text by default but support the `--json` flag as well.

Most commands work offline as shown above (and that's the main purpose of `subwasm`) but for convenience, `subwasm` can also fetch the runtime from a node, this is what happened with you call `subwam info --chain westend`, in that case, `subwasm` does **not** query the remote node for the data via RPC, instead it only fetches (via RPC) the wasm blob, decodes it and calls the runtime direclty and locally.

So using the `--chain` flag is like doing a `get` first to get the runtime locally.

NOTE: if you want to know more about the content of the runtime, you can check out the `meta` (alias for `metadata`) command as well.